# Don't show correct format date time on phpmyadmin when use adddate() function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I have installed mysql and phpmyadmin on centos 6.7. I hvae some database and tables, when i use sql command on phpmyadmin for query date that have sql like this  `select adddate("2016-12-01",m.number) as date from mytalbe m` . it show incorrect format like image below :

[image]

please help me !

Comment: Does it work as expected through the MySQL command line client?

Comment: Can you show your table structure (or at least what data type you're using here)? Also, which phpMyAdmin version are you using?